# Can someone help me with my wallet

Tags: wallet

I create a wallet on bitcoin.org
Now, i cannot find the way to access my wallet and recover my funds. Can someone help me with that. Thank you !

Comment: Which wallet software did you use? What device did you create the wallet on? Did you make backups of the wallet? Without more info, nobody will be able to help you.